# Find duplicate items in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to achieve to check if my array has duplicate items. But in my special case i need to use two dimensional array.

For an array that has 10 items, i managed to build this code, and i am storing values that i need to validate if they have a duplicate value or not is: `$array[0][0]`, `$array[1][0]`, `$array[2][0]`...

```
$arrayItemCount = 10; //means $array[0][0] to $array[9][0]
    for ($p=0;$p<$arrayItemCount;$p++){
        for ($h=0;$h<$arrayItemCount;$h++){
            if ($array[$p][0]==$array[$h][0]){
                $duplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not an expert when it comes to arrays, so any help would be appreciated.

Expected result:

```
$array[0][0] = 5;
$array[1][0] = 99;
$array[2][0] = 5;

echo $duplicate; //1 or true
```

Comment: Just true or false are there any duplicate values anywhere in the array?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hello hitchhiker, yes i need to know if there are duplicate values or not. One duplicate is enough for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function can be used to find duplicate values regardless of the number of dimensions.

```
function hasDuplicates(array $array, array &$values = []): bool
{
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (hasDuplicates($value, $values)) return true;
        } else {
            if (isset($values[$value])) return true;
            $values[$value] = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this example, `$values` is a reference to an array that keeps track of all the numbers that have been evaluated so far. Any time a non-array value is encountered, the function will try to find it in `$values`. If it's found, the function will immediately return true (and recursively return true to the outermost function call).

If the entire array is traversed without finding a duplicate, it will return false.

```
$hasDuplicates = hasDuplicates($your_array);
```